# Is there a shorthand for this multidimensional array declaration in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char field1[45];
char field2[444];
char *fields[] = {
    field1, field2
};
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sprintf(fields[0], "hello\n");
    printf(fields[0]);
}
```

I have no need for accessing the fields using field1 and field2. Is there some shorthand way to do this? I tried the following which doesn't work.

```
char *fields[] = { char[45], char[444] };
```

Basically I guess I want an array that contains character strings of varying length without having to use malloc.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want something like `char fields[45][444];`?

Comment: You can't have an array where the elements have different sizes - which means you have to use an array of pointers to different-sized things instead. `char *fields[] = { &(char[45]){}, &(char[444]){} };` comes to mind, but I don't even know if that compiles, and whether the inner arrays will be read-only if so.

Comment: that doesn't compile for me. but it seems basically like what my original code would do; I guess I will just have to leave field1 and field2 declared and not use them

Comment: Don't use an arbitrary string as the first argument to `printf`.  That will fail if the string contains any format characters (e.g., `%`).  Instead, use `printf("%s", fields[0]);`  (And better yet, add a newline `\n` to the end of the format.)

Comment: @immibis there must be at least one initializer (`0` will do), and they are writable unless declared `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write:

```
char *fields[] = {
    (char[45]) { 0 },
    (char[444]) { 0 }
};
```

I'd suggest against using this design though as it makes it difficult to perform a check that you won't be overrunning the buffer.

Comment: * Idea originally suggested by immibis in comments

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want a struct.

```
struct fields {
    char field1[45];
    char field2[444];
};

struct fields theFields[100];
```

I don't see a multidimensional-array.

Comment: Not exactly, I wanted to be able to access field1 by using fields[0] and field2 by using fields[1]. Which works in my example but I don't have any need for having 'field1' and 'field2' other than declaring fields.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I guess I want an array that contains character strings of varying length without having to use malloc.

To be more precise, you want a "jagged" array, where the *physical* size of each `fields[i]` can be different (i.e., `fields[0]` reserves just enough space for an 8 character string, `fields[1]` reserves just enough space for a 20 character string, etc.), and you still want regular multidimensional array syntax to work.

Unfortunately, you can't do that with regular array declaration syntax.

If you really don't want to mess with dynamic memory, one thing you can try is to set up a large 1D array as your backing store, and then store pointers into that array.  Here's something stupid that I just womped up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define HUGE 128

static char backing_store[HUGE];
static size_t backing_store_used = 0;

char *add_string( const char *str )
{
  char *p = NULL;
  if ( strlen( str ) < HUGE - backing_store_used )
  {
    p = &backing_store[backing_store_used];
    strcpy( p, str );
    backing_store_used += strlen( str ) + 1;
  }
  return p;
}

int main( void )
{
  char *strs[5] = {NULL};

  strs[0] = add_string("foo");
  strs[1] = add_string("blurga");
  strs[2] = add_string("supercalifragilisticexpealidocious");

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
    printf( "strs[%zu] = %s (%zu), strs[%zu][1] = %c\n", i, strs[i], strlen( strs[i] ), i, strs[i][1] );
  }

  int printed = 0;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < HUGE; i++ )
  {
    if ( printed > 80 )
    {
      putchar( '\n' );
      printed = 0;
    }
    printed += printf( isprint( backing_store[i] ) ? "%c " : "'\\0%o' ", backing_store[i] );
  }

  putchar( '\n' );
  return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/stringspace: ./stringspace
strs[0] = foo (3), strs[0][1] = o
strs[1] = blurga (6), strs[1][1] = l
strs[2] = supercalifragilisticexpealidocious (34), strs[2][1] = u
f o o '\00' b l u r g a '\00' s u p e r c a l i f r a g i l i s t i c e x p e a l
i d o c i o u s '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00'
'\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00'
'\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00'
'\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00'
'\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00'
'\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00' '\00'
'\00' '\00'
```

So you can pretend your `strs` array is an array of strings of different *physical* length.

Obviously, you'll need to do some analysis to see how big you need to make your backing store for the number and length of strings you want to save.

This is great for setting up a static list of strings that you don't intend to change.  If you want to edit strings to different lengths, or remove strings, or stuff like that, this gets unpleasant in a hurry, and you're basically writing a broken version of your own dynamic memory manager, at which point you might as well use `malloc` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

What you present is *not* a multidimensional array declaration.  It is a declaration of an array of pointers to `char`, which you happen to initialize as an array of two pointers, one to the first element of each of two `char` arrays.  **It is essential to understand that arrays and pointers are not the same thing**.  In this particular case, one upshot is that the two 1D arrays are not guaranteed to be adjacent in memory, nor laid out in the same order in memory as the pointers to them are in the array.

Since multidimensional arrays are arrays whose elements are arrays, it follows as a corollary that arrays of pointers are not multidimensional arrays.  The facts that values of array type *decay* to pointers may confuse the situation, but it does not change it.

Now in answer to your actual question, <s>no there is no shorthand way to initialize an array of pointers such as you present with a value equivalent to what you present.  Valid pointers point to something, and you must declare that something somewhere (else).</s>  as @immibis mentioned in comments and @M.M previously answered, you can use array literals instead of named arrays.  See @M.M's answer for the syntax.  I reiterate, however, that this is an array of pointers, not a 2D array.

As other answers have already observed, there are other data structures that would provide more guarantees about layout and ordering, and perhaps one of those would suit your actual needs better, but none of them is shorter to type than what you present.

> Basically I guess I want an array that contains character strings of varying length without having to use malloc.

Notwithstanding any of the above, if the working code you presented in fact serves your purpose, there's nothing wrong with it.  However, depending on what you mean by an array of *strings* of varying length, this might be an alternative:

```
char fields[2][444];
```

The two array elements -- each an array of 444 `char`s -- can each accommodate a *string* of any length up to 443 `chars`, as the length of the string depends on the position within the array of the string terminator.  That you don't plan to use 399 bytes of the first element is not necessarily a big deal.

It may also be convenient to do something like this:

```
char fields[][444] = { "a short string", "a somewhat longer string, ya know" };
```

Note that in this case the quoted character sequences are *initializers* for the member arrays. No pointers are involved in this case.